# Angular - provide ng-content to child of child component

Tags: angular

I would like to provide ng-content from parent component to component, which is encapsulated in child component. Here is my code:

**main.component.html**

```
<a-component>
    <item>ITEM 1</item>
</a-component>
```

**a.component.html**

```
<b-component>
    <ng-content select="item"></ng-content>

    <item>ITEM 2</item>
</b-component>
```

**b.component.html**

```
<ng-content select="item"></ng-content>
```

How to send ng-content from main.component to b.component through a.component?

Comment: Have you looked into `ng-template` and `ngTemplateOutlet`? Might work for your usecase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the content you like. In this example, I made it with `select="[item]"`. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9p4scj?file=src/main.ts). Also, note `item` is not a component, it's just an attribute. If you also just want everything show in the child component, you don't need to create a select. just use `ng-content`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  <div style="border:1px solid">
    <h1>child2</h1>
    <ng-content select="[item]">
    </ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child2 {}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, Child2],
  template: `
  <div style="border:1px solid">

    <h1>child1</h1>
    <child-2>
    <p item>from child 1
    <ng-content select="[item]">
    </ng-content>

    </p>
    </child-2>
    </div>
  
  `,
})
export class Child1 {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, Child1],
  template: `
 <child-1>
 <p item>from root</p>
 </child-1>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```